# Can Flutter clear RAM and play with System Settings of the Mobile Device?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a Game booster which basically is like 360 antivirus like it clears the RAM and Boosts the device performance. It should even be able to delete unwanted files on the device. Please help.

Comment: You'll have the handle the platform native side code via a `MethodChannel`

Comment: Just got to know about `Method Channel` They only handle calls and messages of the Android device.

Comment: No, they work cross platform. Check here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels